# OS X - broadcasting HID events

Tags: objective-c, c, driver, hid, iokit

I have a USB gamepad that I'm attempting to write a user-space driver for. Originally, I wrote the driver to work with Linux (using libusb), and everything seems to work fine there.

Basically, I get all the useful data (e.g. X, Y coordinates and button presses) from the device and store it in an array that is printf'd onto the screen. Now I can get this far with OS X easily.

However, I don't know how to broadcast that data so it can be used by other applications. I realize that one workaround is to call CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent, where I could basically map the device's buttons to keystrokes. However, I would rather not use emulated keystrokes because some information (for example the X, Y coordinates) is difficult to represent as keystroke events.

I'm unfamiliar with IOKit, so is there a function available there (or somewhere else buried in Apple documentation) that will help me do this? And, if so, will I have to re-write my current driver to be able to utilize the IOKit/other-Apple-library way? Or is there some, super-easy-to-use function where I can take my data and send it to any foreground application?

Comment: I know this is an older post but would you be able to tell me which set of Docs you used to figure out how to get that data off the device and print it? I'm in a similar situation as you and can't seem to even get that far.

Comment: @Stavros_S I used [libusb](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/) on the OS X implementation as well. Check out [this paste] (http://pastebin.com/nZ6RVvGH) if you want to see a super quick-and-dirty version of what I did.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Will check out your code.

Comment: one last question for you, did you just add the libusb.h to your application directly? The instructions to build the library are pretty vague. I can get it to build the libhidapi64.dylib but when I add that to my project nothing seems to work still.

Comment: You may have already got everything working by now, but I didn't add libusb.h straight to my application. I don't know if this answers your question, but I ran `autoconf && ./configure && make && sudo make install` to build the library to /usr/local/lib. Then when compiling, I added -lusb-1.0 to the gcc/clang commands. You can do the same method in Xcode, but I don't remember how off the top of my head.

Comment: I actually just realized you mentioned you were using libusb and not the hidapi lib, I think they actually build differently.